# Steam Won't Launch - CMultifieldBlob(pSerialized)

Tags: steam

My Steam won't launch. It gives me an error - "Steam.exe (main exception): CMultifieldBlob(pSerialized) - Bad field". What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just delete the `clientregistry.blob` in your Steam folder and **nothing else**, then launch Steam. Steam will just make a new `clientregistry.blob`.

Comment: There is the rare problem when there's something else other than the `clientregistry.blob` is corrupted, but that's not the scope of this question. This is a more targeted (and faster) solution than mine.

Answer (score 7):

SOURCE: [How should I reset the ClientRegistry.blob when needed?](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7241-EYON-2343)

This error is caused by a corrupted `ClientRegistry.blob` file. Most likely, Steam closed incorrectly. Either your computer crashed or the Steam process was killed before Steam finishing writing to the file.

One way to fix this error is by going to your Steam folder (following are common default locations)

- `C:/Program Files/Steam` on 32-bit Windows OS
- `C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam` on 64-bit Windows OS
- `Users/[username]/Library/Application Support/Steam` on Macs

For **Windows OS**, you'll want to delete everything **EXCEPT** `steam.exe` and the `steamapps` directory (this holds your game data). Then, restart Steam and you'll be fine.

For **Mac OS**, just delete everything in that directory and restart Steam.

Comment: If it's a corrupted clientregistry.blob file, just delete that one file.  Steam will happily recreate it on restart.  It takes a little while, as it requires steam to scan for all your games, but it works fine.  I do it quite often, whenever I'm restoring a game I've copied to a different hard drive.

Comment: @Kexlox Yeah, it makes sense but Steam recommends clearing the entire directory except for those things for god-knows-why.

Comment: @Yawus Do you have a source for that?

Comment: @pixel https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=3134-TIAL-4638 But deleting the ClientRegistry.blob has always lead to success for me.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was I went to the Steam site and clicked install.
After I got the installer I clicked it and it said to restore corrupted files or to delete Steam. I clicked restore files and it worked perfectly for me.